# How to solve UnicodeDecodeError in mezzanine?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I am using mezzanine cms. When I scrap the data from the blogspot I got this error

```
blog_id: sanavitastudio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nyros/hs/git_br/2013/Oct-9/healersource/apps/blog_hs/forms.py", line 226, in save
    blog_id=blog_id)
  File "/home/nyros/hs/1a9pinaxenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 150, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/nyros/hs/1a9pinaxenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/nyros/hs/git_br/mezzanine/mezzanine/blog/management/base.py", line 172, in handle
    post, created = BlogPost.objects.get_or_create(**initial)
  File "/home/nyros/hs/1a9pinaxenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 134, in get_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/nyros/hs/1a9pinaxenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 452, in get_or_create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/nyros/hs/git_br/mezzanine/mezzanine/core/models.py", line 221, in save
    super(Displayable, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nyros/hs/git_br/mezzanine/mezzanine/core/models.py", line 77, in save
    super(Slugged, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nyros/hs/git_br/mezzanine/mezzanine/core/models.py", line 46, in save
    super(SiteRelated, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nyros/hs/git_br/mezzanine/mezzanine/core/models.py", line 116, in save
    self.description = strip_tags(self.description_from_content())
  File "/home/nyros/hs/git_br/mezzanine/mezzanine/core/models.py", line 146, in description_from_content
    description = unicode(self)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Code:

```
            import xmltest
            blog_id = xmltest.blogname(self.cleaned_data['blog_id'])

            print(type(blog_id))
            call_command(
                'import_blogger_hs',
                mezzanine_user=request.user.username,
                blog_id=blog_id)
            return False
```

And blogname method for If you give blogname it will automatically scrap the blogID and it is represented as blog_id.

Comment: Can we see your code? Specifically: 
`healersource/apps/blog_hs/forms.py` ?

The easiest way to solve this may be to put all of your strings in u'' strings... #python2problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so now with the code the problem is most likely with `request.user.username` unfortunately the mezzanine code assumes it is receiving an ascii object (what `unicode(self)` in the stacktrace is doing) and is "double encoding" it... grrr!

I would call your method the same way but do this:

```
call_command(
    'import_blogger_hs',
    mezzanine_user=request.user.username.decode('utf-8'),
    blog_id=blog_id)
```

Does that fix the issue?

Comment: Thanks. I have replaced my end as you said. But I got this error DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(500).

Comment: it seems like you might need a different database type for the value you're trying to store? Is this coming from the same place?

Comment: Thanks for reply. please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263478/database-range-error-in-django. I have posted another question for database error.

Comment: Hi @ranman, I found the issue it is related to when the get the data from the blogpost as a string. But it is combination of string and utf-8 or ascii. How to solve this error ?. Please respond my comment regards dhana.