# how to find encoded string in python ?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

Here is my code,

```
In [13]: test = """<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on"><span style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">It’s hard to say what’s happening to us is something happy or not-and to what extend that particular thing is ‘a’ happy thing or not…..don’t believe it???</span><br style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;" /><span style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">Well, when I was relaxing and indulging myself with watchin’ my favourite Chinese drama series, ‘square pegs’; my bro-in law asked me to buy him express bus ticket. And pastu, zuhadi called me up ajak aku gi KLIA hantar Mia g German..lgpun Arep pun nk ikut..I agreed..without knowin, that something will come up later…</span><br style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;" /><span style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">I waited for Zuhadi at Jelatek LRT Putra Station..and after sometimes, he came and told me that Arep tak jd dtg….I knew it already bcoz I had already called Arep n he said that Mia had told(or wanted to tell) Zuhadi tak payah gi KLIA sbb die pun gi ngn KLIA Transit jer n better hantar duit dier yg zuhadi pinjam kat umh jer kan..</span><br style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;" /><span style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">Since Arep pun tak dtg and Zuhadi pun seemed like havin another plan that was to go to Nini’s(Zuhadi’s fren who we mistakenly took her as Zuhadi gf) house(to get sumthin’). When we arrived at her house..but she wasn’t there( she was in Klang)..so I guess u know what we did-went there!</span><br style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;" /><span style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">Along the way we talked bout our planning-Zuhadi get a job at AIA-congrats to him!!!..but me????..no what-so-ever plan yet!..we chatted..chat..chat..and then…..Gek..Gek…Gekk!..</span><br style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;" /><span style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">We heard an awkward sound as we were passing a tol plaza…Then we realized that..THE RIGHT BACK TYRE HAD PUNCTURED!!!</span><br style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;" /><span style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">IT took us almost an hour or so to change it!..we looked around for a car jack..but it was juz not there..luckily there was another car who broke down a long the road..so Zuhadi went and asked’em for that eject thingy..dunno what it called….Baru separuh gune benda alah tu..owner dia ckp yg kembara (keta abg Zuhadi) selalunye letak eject kat co-pilot punyer place..then we found it..hahahaha..tp punye le payah nk gune.sampai patah screw-driver yg Zuhadi gune!!..siap bleeding lg tangan die..kesian siot!!!</span><br style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;" /><span style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">Last skali kitorg tukar tempat nk eject tuh..barulerr terangkat keta tuh!!!(hey..dun blame me!!!..i know nothin’ bout cars ok!)..we tought the ordeal was over, but nahhh!!!!..misery was so sad and tak sampai hat ink leave kitorg!!....Sampai nk mampus kitorg try nk bukak screw tayar yg pancit tu..tak gak bukak2!!!..then I went to the plaza tol and asked for peronda highway..pastu bl dh gi kat kat keta balik..barulerr ble bukak tayar pancit tuh!!!..AKHIRNYA!!!!!</span><br style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;" /><span style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">So we continued our journey in meeting Nini n took her n Hazani(her fren) back to her house (Klang is where she’s havin her practicum). And I arrived home at almost 2a.m.</span><br style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;" /><span style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">Well..why am I tellin’ this???...hahahha..you may think it was a terrible ordeal..bad experience..pengalaman pahit..but nahhh..i found it was very interesting, becoz we really had a good time—becoz if I were not there..Zuhadi will hav to face the prob alone and I was surely gonna be boring and depressing !!..i admit I didn’t do nothing much..but at least I was there to accompany him n jd penghibur tidak rasmi!..and if I didn’t go out wif him..i’d never face that kind of situation-b4 this..i never experienced tayar pancit!! hehehhee…</span><br style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;" /><span style="background-color: #1c1c1c; color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;">"And you know what????...i got it all in my digicam !"</span></div>
   ....: 2013-10-09 18:30:00.001000
   ....: O’ happy day!!!"""

In [14]: type(test)
Out[14]: str

In [15]: test.encode('utf-8')
```

And I got the output like this,

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 209: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The above error raised due to test is already encoded. But I am using type keyword it shows the str. My question is it combination of string and ascii or (utf-8) ?. I need to find the given string is encoded or normal str. If it is encoded do nothing or else do convert encode. Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, `str` is *already* encoded.

Because you are trying to encode an already encoded value, Python tries to *decode* it to `unicode` for you first using the default ASCII codec, and that fails.

The encoding of the `str` value depends on how you entered the string literal. In the terminal, it'll use the terminal codec. In a source file, it depends on your editor what codec was used to save the file. If loaded from another source (an external file, stream or network socket) it very much depends on standards for that communication channel what codec has been used, and whether or not your program can retrieve the exact codec used. Sometimes it is not known and not reliably extractable.

You cannot detect the difference between a 'normal' `str` and encoded data, because **all** `str` values are encoded data. You'd normally look for `unicode` values and use `.encode()` on *those* to get `str` values:

```
if isinstance(value, unicode):
    # encode to UTF8 first
    value = value.encode('utf8')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Pieter. I am using Komodo editor. How to find codec in Komodo editor ?

Comment: @dhana: did you enter the HTML by hand into the source text in Komodo? Or did you use a URL library to load it from a remote server instead?

Comment: @dhana: See the [Komodo documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.1/prefs.html#Internationalization) itself for what codec is used for the Python source code.

Comment: @Pieter I have used URL library to load it from a blogspot remote server. I get the posts from blogspot using mezzanine package.

Comment: Then post that code and we can take a look at how to detect the codec used. Do you need unicode output? How are you going to parse the HTML?

Comment: Mezzanine is just a CMS built on top of Django; your problem is not related to Mezzanine (other than that you probably need `unicode` instead of `str` to insert into the database).

Comment: Thanks Here the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262960/how-to-solve-unicodedecodeerror-in-mezzanine/19263093#comment28561684_19263093. please solve my problem. I will accept this answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38948/discussion-between-dhana-and-martijn-pieters)